# React-table version 7 all the data appears on One page

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am trying to implement react-table
I have 750 rows and they all appear on the first page although I have controlled pagination that is telling me I am on page 1 of 68
But all the 750 rows - as I said - appear on one page .

All features are working, except for that issue.
I am fetching the data ( altogether ) from an API and sending them to the Table.
this is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  useSortBy,
  useTable,
  useGlobalFilter,
  usePagination
} from 'react-table';

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    canNextPage,
    canPreviousPage,
    pageOptions,
    gotoPage,
    pageCount,
    setPageSize,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    setGlobalFilter
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  );

  const { globalFilter, pageIndex, pageSize } = state;

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalFilter filter={globalFilter} setFilter={setGlobalFilter} />
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                  {column.render('header')}
                  <span>
                    {column.isSorted
                      ? column.isSortedDesc
                        ? ' '
                        : ' '
                      : ''}
                  </span>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <span>
          Page{' '}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page
          <input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const pageNumber = e.target.value
                ? Number(e.target.value) - 1
                : 0;
              gotoPage(pageNumber);
            }}
          />
        </span>
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={(e) => setPageSize(Number(e.target.value))}
        >
          {[10, 25, 50].map((pageSize) => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {'<<'}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          Previous
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          Next
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {'>>'}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

const GlobalFilter = ({ filter, setFilter }) => {
  return (
    <span>
      Search:{' '}
      <input value={filter || ''} onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)} />
    </span>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad
I should use `page` instead of `rows`
Like this

```
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td
                      {...cell.getCellProps()}
                      className="p-2 border border-collapse"
                    >
                      {cell.render('Cell')}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
```